# When is the Community Moderator Election 2023?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering when the next Community Moderator Election will be held?

Members have proven to be incredibly valuable in providing active support. The platform has grown, which also means more "logistics" for the moderators. More moderators, people who care about the platform, will increase the quality of the platform (when chosen correctly of course).

On the whole, I think it would benefit the platform if we start a new Community Moderator Election.

Would love to hear your thoughts.

EDIT: What is the process of starting a new election?

Answer (score 2):

I am definitely open to a new community moderator election, however, I also want to note that basically all moderator permissions (within the context of this site), are achievable by getting enough points and earning access to those permissions.

Comment: I thought only moderators could actually close votes and others with certain reputation could only vote to close a question, but this is indeed not true.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a good idea to start new elections after a year.

I see that the first [Community Moderator Elections](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/election) started in the 25 of April 2022 and ended on the 10 of May 2022.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, there should be an election sometime very very soon, per a email from Sasha (a Stack Exchange Community Engagement & Enablement Team member) and have pinged them to reply here letting us know when the next election should happen.

Update:

> We have a number of sites that need elections this month, so we are working on getting things scheduled. Your site is definitely on the list and we will follow up soon.